# Trying to update from Git - not working

Tags: git

I'm trying to update changes I made and committed to a remote branch. It isn't working.

I've fetched the branches, checked out the branch I want, but nothing is showing in the logs and the files aren't up to date. What am I missing?

Comment: the remote branch is being tracked.

Comment: Please add more detail. Which branch isn't being updated, origin/some-branch-name or some-branch-name? Exactly which commands are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not much clear but what I can explain here is how to make your changes  reach remote branch

Steps
1) git checkout -b branchName orgin/branchName 
2) Make changes 
3) git add 
4) git commit
5) git fetch +git rebase orgin/branchName (for safer side)
6) git push orgin branchName

Note- keep in mind if keep the local branch name same as the remote branch otherwise it will create a new branch